# Trying to make an ArrayList; compiler cannot resolve "add"

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm supposed to make an Array of objects that will be created on a loop, but for some reason, I can't add things to the array.

I have this

```
public class _10Weather {        
    List<Weather> daysoff = new ArrayList<Weather>();        
}
```

When I do

```
daysoff.add
```

it says that it can't resolve add. I've been reading a lot about arraylists and questions here on how to add, but it seems that it should work just like that.

Edit: Those are the imports, I've been trying a ton of things.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
```

Comment: `import java.util.List` and `import java.util.ArrayList`?

Comment: Can you please post the code which is on top of your class defination, where the import statements are present?

Comment: Ensure you are typing the correct syntax. `daysoff.add(weatherInstance);` and make sure you do the necessary import.

Comment: Please post an SSCCE

Comment: @m0skit0 : What is SSCCE?

Comment: Yeah, i'm pretty new to this and i don't know what SSCCE means, sry.

Comment: "SSCCE" stands for "Short Self-Contained Compilable Example"; see also http://www.sscce.org/ . Also sometimes called a [mcve].

Comment: Please show us the line where you call `add`. Just `daysoff.add` will indeed give you this error. `daysoff.add(someInstance)` should work, where `someInstance` is an instance of `Weather`.

Comment: That's where i'm not sure, since "Weather" is a class with attributes, when i do `daysoff.add(someInstance)`, `someInstance`must have the parameters of the constructor from the Weather class?

Im pretty new to java and im trying it bymyself, that's why the basic questions, sry.

Comment: I hope my answer has clarified things. Object-orientation can be confusing when you are new. You did well to find a book on Java, if you don't have one. Books from O'Reilly and Manning are usually good; there are also free online books.

Comment: I'll do it, thanks @S.L.Barth !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```
daysoff.add
```

then you're asking the compiler to look for a *field* named `add`; a data member. The java.util.List class does not have a field named `add`, so it reports that it cannot resolve this.

You should call

```
daysoff.add(someInstance);
```

where `someInstance` is an instance of `Weather`.
Then, the compiler will recognize that you are calling the *method* named `add`.

By the time you do this, you already have defined `someInstance`. Adding the instance is separate from creating it.
Let's say that the constructor of `Weather` takes a string parameter. You'd get something like this:

```
Weather someInstance = new Weather("sunny");
daysoff.add(someInstance);
```

In the first line, you've created the instance. In the second one, you're using it.

In this case, it's also important to make sure you have the right type of List; Java AWT also has a class named List, wich is different from java.util.List. The reason people asked you to tell us your imports, is so that they could see if you weren't accidentally using `java.awt.List` instead of `java.util.List`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Then, if i understood correctly, this:
`Weather we = new Weather(11,11,"Cold");`

    `List<Weather> daysoff = new ArrayList<Weather>();`

    `daysoff.add(we);`

Should work, right?

Comment: @JuanPa Yes, that should work.

Comment: It keeps telling me that its unable to resolve the symbol "add" and that "we" its an unknown class
`List<Weather> daysoff = new ArrayList<Weather>();
    Weather we = new Weather(11,11,"Cold");
    daysoff.add(we);`

It should be working, i'll try to do it all again on a clean new class.

Comment: @JuanPa Strange, it should be working. I tried it on Ideone.com [here](http://ideone.com/9X4Pbp).  Trying a clean approach might indeed help. If you're using an IDE (a development tool - like Netbeans, Eclipse, or IntelliJ) it should have an option named "Clean", or something similar. That option removes remnants of earlier compilations that sometimes wreak havoc with a new attempt.

Comment: Yeah, I'll be trying that now, and im using intelliJ so I'll search that option. Well, since it should work, and I understood how Arrays work now, I'll get this question answered, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @JuanPa You're welcome!